# Algorithm to compute differences in daytime using Euclidean distance

Tags: elementary-number-theory, metric-spaces

This question came into my mind, when reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737942/clustering-in-pythonscipy-with-space-and-time-variables) on how to cluster data with respect to what time of the day it was observed.

Say you have a number $h$, where $h\in\{0,\cdots,23\}$. Is there an operation $S$ such that for any $t$, with $0<t<23.99$,
$$
d(t,h):=|t-S(h)|
$$ 
will give you the difference in daytime between $t$ and $h$. For example, if $h=22$ and $t=2$, then $d(t,h)$ should be $4$ (and not $20$).

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible, but I doubt it. The function $d(t,h)$ is symmetric in $t$ and $h$ (they can switch roles), so this kind of a formula doesn't look promising. For example, the range of $S$ should be a subset of $[t-12,t+12]$, i.e. $S$ should depend on $t$ also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such operation. Indeed, if $t=h$ then $|h-S(h)|=d(h,h)=0$, so $S(h)$ should be equal to $h$ for all $h$, but the operation $S(h)=h$ does not satisfy our requirements.

Comment: LOL! +1 ${}{}{}$